# Python: Why does this code execute?

Tags: python, for-loop, scope, while-loop

I'm a beginner in python and using v2.7.2 here's what i tried to execute in the command prompt

```
 p = 2
 while(p>0):
     for i in range(10):
          print i+1 , p
          p-=1
```

The **expected** output was

```
1 2
2 1
```

However the **actual** output is

```
1 2
2 1
3 0
4 -1
5 -2
6 -3
7 -4
8 -5
9 -6
10 -7
```

Why does this happen? and How do i achieve the expected behavior?

Comment: Is that really the output or does it go all the way up to 10?

Comment: @doctorlove it definitely is not the output OP gets.

Comment: Sorry! I made an edit to it! Thanks!

Comment: Your code doesn't produce the actual output you print. They way you write it, only the first five lines are shown.

Comment: looks like someone edited it again! i'll fix it thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The while condition is only tested again after the for loop finishes. You could do this instead

```
p = 2
for i in range(10):
    if p <= 0:
        break
    print i+1 , p
    p-=1
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the [output I get](http://ideone.com/VvKjAI):

```
1 2
2 1
3 0
4 -1
5 -2
6 -3
7 -4
8 -5
9 -6
10 -7
```

Your question as to why it runs.  Your **outer most conditional** is a `while` loop, which is true upon the first execution, however it runs right into a **nested for loop**.  When this happens the `while`, will not be checked until the `for` loop **finishes its first execution** (which is why p = -7).

What you want is [this](http://ideone.com/UWt2NV):

```
p = 2
for i in range(10):
    if p <= 0:
        break
    print i+1 , p
    p-=1
```

which gives output:

```
1 2
2 1
```

Comment: can you please make it 

`1 2`
`2 1`

Thats what i'm looking for thanks!

Comment: @JosyulaKrishna fixed.  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: No, now `i` isn't changing

Comment: @gnibbler I just ran it in ideone and included the link to the output.

Comment: Yes, now it matches my answer exactly :p

Comment: @gnibbler indeed it does :)  .  It is why I give all the upboats =p

Comment: @Woot4Moo, you should change/remove the final line about swapping the `while` and the `for`

Comment: Thanks woot4moo and gnibbler can you guys please look at this [code](http://ideone.com/nQVfGe) i want it stop whenever wt<0 but it doesn't i've modified it according to your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to python :-)

You can try this:

```
p = 2
for i in range(1, p+1):
    print i,
print
for i in range(p, 1, -1):
    print i,
```

This will print the desired output. Not only for 2 but also if you change the value of p, it will print the same output.

range function can take three arguments viz start, stop and step. If you give range(x), it will take start as 0, and step as 1 and go up to x(x is not included). If you give range(y, x), it will start from y and go up to x with default step value as 1.

In the example, I used range(p, 0, -1) which takes start point as 'p', step as -1 and decrement the value of p until 1 and quits. To read more about range, click [here](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/range.html).

Comment: Thank you! however i'm trying to solve it by using conditionals.

Comment: @JosyulaKrishna Conditionals? You mean through if statement or through while loop?